# Python Get MIME of s3 object on Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, mime-types

I have a lambda that triggers upon `s3 PutObject`. Before proceeding the lambda needs to check if the file is actually a video file or not (mp4 in my case). File extension is not helpful because that can be fake. So I have tried checking [MIME using FileType](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/) which works in local machine.
I don't want to download large files from s3, just some portion and save in local machine to check if that's mp4 or not.
So far I tried this (on local machine) -

```
import boto3
import filetype
from time import sleep

REGION = 'ap-southeast-1'

tmp_path = "path/src/my_file.mp4"

start_byte = 0
end_byte = 9000

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=REGION)

resp = s3.get_object(
    Bucket="test", 
    Key="MVI_1494.MP4", 
    Range='bytes={}-{}'.format(start_byte, end_byte)
    )

# the file
object_content = resp['Body'].read()

print(type(object_content))
with open(tmp_path, "wb") as binary_file:
    # Write bytes to file
    binary_file.write(object_content)

sleep(5)
kind = filetype.guess_mime(tmp_path)
print(kind)
```

But this always return `None` as mimetype. I think I am not saving the binary file properly, any help would really save my day.

TLDR: Download small portion of large file from s3 -> save in tmp storage -> get mime.

Comment: You're setting `start_byte` and using it to get one byte of the MP4 (the 100th byte).  Perhaps you meant to set `start_byte` and `end_byte` and use those?

Comment: start_byte = 0
start_byte = 100

this is wrong

Comment: Also, you'll want to read at least 8k of the file, some of the matchers in that library needs at least that much data.

Comment: Fixed typo of end_byte. I have used `start - end 1 and 9000`, still getting `None`.
@AnonCoward @Sharuzzaman Ahmat Raslan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You dont need to save file on disk for `filetype` lib.

`guess_mime` function accept `bytes` datatype as well.

[image: mime type]

Comment: Do not post images. Instead, write some code that the OP can copy and better test with.

Comment: Code is already provided above, just remove some lines from code provided above.

Answer (score 1):

Boto3 has a function [S3.Client.head_object:](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object)

> The HEAD action retrieves metadata from an object without returning
> the object itself. This action is useful if you're only interested in
> an object's metadata. To use HEAD, you must have READ access to the
> object.

You can call this method to get metadata object associated with S3 bucket item.

```
metadata = s3client.head_object(Bucket='MyBucketName', Key='MyS3ItemKey')
```

This metadata includes a `ContentType` property, you can use this property to check the object type.

OR

If you can't trust this `ContentType` as this can be faked. You can simply save the object's MIME type in DynamoDB while uploading it. You can read the type from there whenever you want.

OR

You can simply create a Lambda that will get triggered, you can download the object in the Lambda as it has around 512MB as ephemeral storage. You can determine the content type there and update it, as you can also set some metadata when you upload the object and later edit it as your needs change.

Comment: No it can not detect fake files. If I upload an image with mp4 extension it will still output based on file extension.

Comment: One of the quickest solution coming in mind, just save the MIME type in DynamoDB while uploading the object. Read the type from there whenever you need.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately can't do that. It has to start after getting the object in s3 bucket.